# Can the corporation that I work for (I am not salary or a subcontractor) use my personal information & home address for business and billing purposes?

Tags: corporate-law, personal-information

I have a corporate credit card that is utilized for business purposes at the location I work, which is not where corporate headquarters is.

Today the business/ billing address was changed by the corporation I work for to my PERSONAL HOME ADDRESS WITHOUT my permission! I was notified via email by the credit card company about the change.
I have messaged the credit card not giving permission to do that and I am restricted from changing it on my own.

I do not work from home. I do not utilize a corporate credit card for purchases or deliveries to my home. My employer does not operate out of my home address.

1. Can my employer do that?
2. How do I stop this immediately?

Comment: Is this an employer you deal with face to face, where you have done *scrupulous and non-starry-eyed* due diligence as to their genuine character... rather than some "voice on the Internet" scam of some sort?   Beacuse we get a lot of "employment arrangements" where a bunch of guys working together in an Internet cafe in Serbia convince people that they are "employees", but all they really do is trick them into doing money laundering, advance-fee scams, and the like. Getting a credit card in your name would be right in line.

Comment: Where are you and the employer located. Privacy laws differ greatly from one place to another.

Comment: You should have a look at personal money & finance SE -> https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=employment+scam

Comment: If you aren't an employee or subccontractor, what are you?

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the structure of your company's arrangement with the credit card company, as well. I am familiar with at least one setup where each cardholder is issued a card **in their own name** to be used as a charge card, pending reimbursement from central accounts for approved expenses.

For that organization, each cardholder is responsible for paying off their card balance each month (one can claim expenses mid-trip, if necessary), and failure to pay it off is a hit on their personal credit - which would explain why the bank needs the home address for each cardholder. Essentially, they have a card which is only authorized for official expenses, but any mistakes made (eg, improper charges, failing to file an expense report in a timely manner, etc) fall to the cardholder to remedy. I think this is meant to provide more incentive for proper management of funds, as they are also rather aggressive at searching out misconduct and fraud among those provided with charge cards.

For that organization, the answer to your second question (how can I stop that) would be to return the card to the credit card issuer. Doing so may not be without consequences. However, as I mentioned, each card which goes to an individual's address is also in that individuals name. The very few cards not associated with an individual are strictly limited and each charge more rigorously checked (eg, fleet cards used to refuel and maintain the vehicles, where the mileage is tracked to make sure someone isn't filling up their own car, too). Those cards all keep the office as their billing address.